# Implementing multiple services in a single Java app

Tags: java, maven, cxf

I have two WSDL files for different services. Both services work great independently, but if I include both services in the same eclipse project I get several instances of the following errors:

```
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://schemas.foobar.com/oms/2010/10/Models}City.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.models.BusinessUnitData.city
        at com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.models.BusinessUnitData
        at protected com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.models.BusinessUnitData com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.CreateBusinessUnitRequest.businessUnitData
        at com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.CreateBusinessUnitRequest
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.CreateBusinessUnitRequest])
        at public com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.CCreateBusinessUnitRequest com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.ObjectFactory.createCCreateBusinessUnitRequest()
        at com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.ObjectFactory
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.AddToStructureRequest.unitStructureData
        at com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.AddToStructureRequest
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.AddToStructureRequest])
There's no ObjectFactory with an @XmlElementDecl for the element {http://schemas.foobar.com/oms/2010/10/Models}ClientKey.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.models.BusinessUnitData.clientKey
        at com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.models.BusinessUnitData
        at protected com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.models.BusinessUnitData com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.CreateBusinessUnitRequest.businessUnitData
        at com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.CreateBusinessUnitRequest
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.CreateBusinessUnitRequest])
        at public com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.CCreateBusinessUnitRequest com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.ObjectFactory.createCCreateBusinessUnitRequest()
        at com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.ObjectFactory
        at protected javax.xml.bind.JAXBElement com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.AddToStructureRequest.unitStructureData
        at com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.AddToStructureRequest
        at @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlSeeAlso(value=[class com.foobar.schemas.oms._2010._10.businessunit.AddToStructureRequest])
```

These errors completely fill my terminal window, so I don't know how many times this happens.

I'm generating the stub code one of two ways. First I tried generating both with wsdl2java, then packing the compiled code into a jar and included that in my build path. I also tried creating a new maven project with the cxf code-gen plugin. Then I ran "mvn install" and included the generated code as a maven dependency. Both techniques produce the same results. Each service works fine on it's own. But if both are included in the project, I get the Object Factory errors.

What causes this type of error? Can it be fixed with a jaxb binding file? If so, I'm new to webservices, and have been having trouble finding an example binding file to learn how to format it.

Comment: Are there namespace collisions? Are there Java types generated with the same name and package from both WSDLs?

Comment: I think so, but I'm not sure how to check to be positive. The code generator creates 8 packages. I think some objects are reused in some of the methods.

Comment: Use a diff script/tool on the generated directory structures to detect collisions.

Comment: Yes there are namespace collisions. For example, Service A and Service B both have an Update method in the same namespace.

Comment: I'd agree that modifying your JAXB configuration is a potential solution. There are some [sample mapping files on my blog](http://illegalargumentexception.blogspot.co.uk/2011/04/java-jax-ws-web-services-and-clients.html#ws_bindings).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this maven plugin to generate classes from the WSDL:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
    <artifactId>cxf-codegen-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.1</version>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.cxf</groupId>
            <artifactId>cxf-rt-bindings-soap</artifactId>
            <version>2.7.1</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>generate-jaxb</id>
            <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            <configuration>
                <additionalJvmArgs>-Dfile.encoding=UTF8</additionalJvmArgs>
                <wsdlOptions>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/YourWSDL1.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                            <extraarg></extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>your.app.pkg1</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                    <wsdlOption>
                        <wsdl>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/wsdl/YourWSDL2.wsdl</wsdl>
                        <extraargs>
                            <extraarg>-wsdlLocation</extraarg>
                            <extraarg></extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-client</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>-p</extraarg>
                            <extraarg>your.app.pkg2</extraarg>
                        </extraargs>
                    </wsdlOption>
                </wsdlOptions>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>wsdl2java</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

And specify different packages for each WSDL file you have. All classes according to different WSDL files will be generated in different packages and you won't be facing any collisions.

Answer (score 0):

Try these tutorials explaining the implementation of multiple web services in a java application:

http://java.dzone.com/articles/tip-multiple-web-service

http://www2.sys-con.com/itsg/virtualcd/webservices/archives/0308/zade/index.html

Comment: Thanks for the links. But it looks like they don't have the info I'm missing. If the WSDL defines a namespace, is there a way I can change it to avoid a collision?